# Reason for form not showing although I added it in the template

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have made a new Comment Model in my Django Project but the form is not showing in the browser although I added the form in the template.

**Here is the models.py**

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField(max_length=300)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.pk)
```

**Here is the views:**

```
def comment_create(request, self):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
    user = User.objects.get(user=request.user)

    c_form = CommentModelForm()

    context = {
        'post': post,
        'user': user,
        'c_form': c_form,
    }
    return context
```

**Here is the forms.py**

```
class CommentModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    body = forms.CharField(label='',
                            widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Add a comment...'}))
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('body',)
```

**Here is the urls.py**

```
    path('blogs/comment', comment_create, name='comment-post'),
```

**Here is the template:**

```
                <form action="" method="POST"class='ui fluid form'>
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value={{post.id}}>
                      {{ c_form }}
                    <button type="submit" name="submit_c_form" class="">Send</button>
                </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to get the type of request, I added a if/else for GET and POST requests. Added form.is_valid check.

In your function you are trying to get a kwarg form the url but you don't have a kwarg in your path.

```
path('blogs/<slug:slug>/comment', comment_create, name='comment-post'),
```

views.py

```
def comment_create(request, self):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=self.kwargs['slug'])

    if request.method == 'POST': # If user submitted form
        c_form = CommentModelForm(request.POST) # Get form response
        if c_form.is_valid(): # Chekc if form is valid
            c_form.user = User.objects.get(user=request.user) # Get user and add it to form
            c_form.post = post # Add post to form
            c_form.save() # Save form
    else:
        c_form = CommentModelForm() # Pass form

    context = {
        'post': post,
        'c_form': c_form,
    }
    return render(request, 'app/comment.html', context) # change template
```

forms.py

```
class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['body'] # When I set tuples it normally gives me an error
```

Comment: it still didn't show up, the comments made in the admin is showing but I can not submit from browser. There is no form showing

Comment: I made some major changes to the code. You just have to pass the slug from your `Post` view to the `Comment` create view and it should work.
@A_K